# importing data from a CSV in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, csv

I have a CSV file that I need to use in a bash script. The CSV is formatted like so.

```
server1,file.name
server1,otherfile.name
server2,file.name
server3,file.name
```

I need to be able to pull this information into either an array or in some other way so that I can then filter the information and only pull out data for a single server that i can then pass to another command within the script.

I need it to go something like this.

```
Import workfile.csv
check hostname | return only lines from workfile.csv that have the hostname as column one and store column 2 as a variable.
find / -xdev -type f -perm -002 | compare to stored info | chmod o-w all files not in listing
```

I'm stuck using bash because of the environment that I'm working in.

Comment: Use grep to find the lines that match the hostname. Use awk with FS="," to get the 2nd column.  If you don't need to index the array, you can store the whole list in a single space- or newline delimited string.  Then you can use a for in loop to iterate through your filtered data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csv can be to big for adding all filenames in the find parameter list.
You also do not want to call find in a loop for every line in the csv.

Solution:
First make a complete list of files in a tmp file.
Second parse the csv and filter the files.
Third is chmod -w.

The next solution stores the files in a tmp 
Make a script that gets the servername as a parameter.
See comment in the code:

```
# Before EDIT:
# Hostname by parameter 1
# Check that you have a hostname
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0 hostname"
   # Exit script, failure
   exit 1
fi
hostname=$1

# Edit, get hostname by system call
hostname=$(hostname) 
# Or: hostname=$(hostname -s)

# Additional check
if [ ! -f workfile.csv ]; then
    echo "inputfile missing"
    exit 1
fi

# After edits, ${hostname} is now filled.
find / -xdev -type f -perm -002 -name "${file}" > /tmp/allfiles.tmp

# Do not use cat workfile.csv | grep ..., you do not need to call cat
# grep with ^ for beginning of line, add a , for a complete first field
# grep "^${hostname}," workfile.csv
# cut for selecting second field with delimiter ','
# cut -d"," -f2
# while read file => can be improved with xargs but lets start with this.

grep "^${hostname}," workfile.csv | cut -d"," -f2 | while read file; do
   # Using sed with #, not /, since you need / in the search string
   # Variable in sed mist be outside the single quotes and in double quotes
   # Add $ after the file for end-of-line
   # delete the line with the file (#searchstring#d)
   sed -i '#/'"${file}"'$#d' /tmp/allfiles.tmp  
done
echo "Review /tmp/allfiles.tmp before chmodding all these files"
echo "Delete the echo and exit when you are happy"
# Just an exit for testing
exit
# Using < is for avoiding a call to cat
</tmp/allfiles.tmp xargs chmod -w
```

It might be easier when you can chmod -w all the files and chmod +w the files in the csv. This is a little different than you asked, since all files from the csv are writable after this process, maybe you do not want that.

Comment: This should work great! However, is there a way to have the {hostname} var be set to the the simple hostname? i.e. hostname -s The csv is set up with simple hostnames not the FQDN. If not I'm sure we can just change the CSV.

Comment: See edit. Note: Better formatting is done with var's for the inputfile and tmpfile. Also remove tmpfile at the end of the script.